# What is the difference between these two Javascript arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, numbers

[image]

One is built like this:

```
var l1 = [23, 50, 63, 90, 10, 30, 155, 23, 18]
```

And the other is having elements pushed into it via browser automation:

```
var test = []
list1.each(($el) => {
    return test.push(+$el.get(0).innerText)
})
```

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking for.

Comment: This is just developer tools reporting them differently. Their structure is identical.

Answer (score 0):

First one is mutated **after** logging, second one is logged after mutating. 
Try the following in the console:

```
var arr = [];
console.log(arr);//will log [] but can expand to an item with name 'one'
console.table(arr);//the actual value of arr at the time of logging
console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));//also actual value when logging
arr.push({name:'one'})
```

Comment: I tried this but I am getting back an empty table and empty array on the last two log statements.


`var arr = [];
    console.log(arr);//will log [] but can expand to an item with name 'one'
    console.table(arr);//the actual value of arr at the time of logging
    console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));//also actual value when logging
    list1.each(($el) => {
        arr.push(+$el.get(0).innerText)
    })`

Comment: @QasimHassan The point was to show that console.log will show the object in the console as the object is right now (expand and it'll show the pushed item).

Answer (score 0):

I believe .each returns an object with the value. So if you where to get the type of the $el than it would return obj and not number.